# How to implement a query only sub- in DDD

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design

for the last few months we are trying to refactor and improve the architecture and style of our back-end services based on DDD and Hexagonal-architecture. Unfortunately we are very new to DDD and its best practices.

Our product is about fleet management and monitoring. One feature we have is that users can get reports of the vehicles under their managements. Mostly these reports are simple queries on the database with some aggregations and domain logic in the application layer. This is were our problems arises. For most of application, we used CQRS and defined command/query handlers in our application layer. Dependencies our injected to this handlers and our databases and caches are abstracted using repositories etc.

How ever for the report features(I don't know that it is appropriate to call it a sub-domain or not), we don't know what to do and how to design the entities. Some of this reports are complicated and involve joining, validating  etc on multiple datasets fetched for db, some other are very simple queries, squeezing them all inside a query handler doesn't seem appropriate and we don't know whether we need aggregates here or not. So we are quit stuck and confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to think about is [OLTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_transaction_processing) (Online Transaction Processing) vs [OLAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing) (Online Analytical Processing).  This is nothing to do with DDD and very much about data structures and the problem they are trying to solve.

In short, OLTP is about supporting transactions in applications (e.g. inserts & updates) by leveraging referential integrity and so on; OLAP is about reporting and analytics and structuring the data to better support that.

It depends on how full-on your reporting needs are (functional requirements, complexity of the data structures / DDD model, the number of look-ups, data volumes, user behavior, data volatility, and so on).  If you think the trades-offs justify it then you may want to logically segment your application between what supports the main functionality of the app and what is reporting related.

There's a few options for how you might do this:

- DDD code & OLTP database; complimented by reporting code and OLAP database.  This option is one of the most heavy-handed, but it's also the easiest to understand - total seperation.
- DDD code across the entire app, with "reporting" as a side part to your otherwise "pure" DDD. Database structures to support as you see fit.
- DDD code, with all "reporting" seamlessly and elegantly blended into the existing pure DDD code. Database structures to support as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: How would you do it if you weren't trying to apply DDD patterns?  Do that.

---

Reports are, as a rule, read-only.  They are just copies of information in a convenient shape.

What that means is that you don't need "clusters of associated objects that we treat as a unit for the purpose of data changes" (aggregates) because we aren't changing the data.  You don't need repositories and factories because you aren't managing aggregate lifetimes.  You don't need entities, because you don't need rules of information change.

"Value Objects" can sometimes be useful, but copying information into a value so that you can read it back out again is a waste of time.

(The exception to this would probably be something like a stand alone app, where your report is a description of the information currently stored within your in-memory aggregates.)